# Get text content of html tags like js textcontent property for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to get the full text content of each tag. For example, if we have something like this:

```
html_code = """
<body>
    <h1>hello<b>there</b>how are you?</h1>
</body>"""
```

I want to get this result:

- For the `body` tag: `''` (nothing - without any children elements)
- For the `h1` tag: `'hello there how are you?'` (with all children elements)
- For the `b` tag: `'there'` (with all children elements)

I tried many things but none gives me that result. Any suggestions?

Comment: This question has already been asked today and also has been asked many times before. Have you tried searching existing answers?

Comment: can you give me a link dude?i think no one of them return result like this

Comment: @behzadmehrabi dude, QHarr is right. There are an ABUNDANCE of examples to do this on SO, and simple google search as well. What have you tried?

Comment: @chitown88 can you give a link dude?

Comment: You say you tried many things. What did you try?

Comment: I use beautifulsoup, html2text, inscripits and little bit scrapy but none of them give that result

Comment: Cool. What exactly have you tried with beautifulsoup? Put that in you’re question. Show what output or error it gave you. And what your expected is (which you have included). This gives users something to work off of and shows that you’ve attempted it on your own first.

Comment: Oooohh. Ok I understand your question now. I misunderstood at first. You basically want the text that directly follows the specific tag. So you basically want body tag (without any children elements). Then the direct content of h1 tag (including all children elements), and b tag.

Comment: Exactly!that's what javascript textcontent property do

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to work with the `.find()` or `.find_all()` then whether you want to include children tags or not, utilize `recursive` parameter:

```
html_code = """
<body>
    <h1>hello<b>there</b>how are you?</h1>
</body>"""

import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'html.parser')


body_text = soup.body.find_all(text=True, recursive=False) 
h1_text = soup.h1.find_all(text=True, recursive=True) 
b_text = soup.b.find_all(text=True, recursive=False) 

body_text = ' '.join(body_text).strip()
h1_text = ' '.join(h1_text).strip()
b_text = ' '.join(b_text).strip()


print ('body: %s\nh1: %s\nb: %s' %(body_text, h1_text, b_text))
```

**Output:**

```
body: 
h1: hello there how are you?
b: there
```